# Can I export values from an arrow function in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use pass lng lat variables to the a google maps component from a google's geocode API, however since the geocode function is an arrow function I'm unable to use the values outside of this function. Is there any way to fix this? I need to be able to use the constants lat and lng from the geocode function and pass them to the lat and lang properties in the MapWithMarker constant

```
Geocode.fromAddress("5th Avenue New York").then(
      response => {
         const{ lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;


      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );


    const MapWithAMarker = withGoogleMap(props =>
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={0}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
    );
```

./src/components/dashboard/ProductDetails.js
  Line 107:  'lat' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 107:  'lng' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 110:  'lat' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 110:  'lng' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

You can cache them such as:

```
const MyMapComponent = function(props) {
    const [position, setPosition] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        Geocode.fromAddress("5th Avenue New York").then(
          response => {
             setPosition(response.results[0].geometry.location);             

          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
          }
        );
    }, [])

    if (!position) {
        return null;
    }   

    return <MapWithAMarker {...props} lat={position.lat} lng={position.lng} />
}

const MapWithAMarker = withGoogleMap(props =>
  const     
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={0}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
  >
    <Marker
      position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
);
```

And now you can use `MyMapComponent` as a decorator of `MapWithAMarker`.

Comment: That didnt work unfortunately :/ it throws InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number because lat & lng aren't getting their values from response

Comment: It happens, as `Geocode.fromAddress("5th Avenue New York")` returns a promise. 
It means the code placed into onResolve callback will be executed in microtask. 
So, it's better to create a bit more infrastructure. I extended the answer

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is

```
var MapWithAMarker;
Geocode.fromAddress("5th Avenue New York").then(
    response => {
        const{ lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        MapWithAMarker = withGoogleMap(props =>
          <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={0}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
          >
            <Marker
              position={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
            />
          </GoogleMap>
        );

  }
)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And then you do use it like

```
if( MapWithAMarker ){
    // do whatever you want;
}
```